# Serving local file:/// links and AppCache

Tags: html, local-storage, offline, auto-update, html5-appcache

I'm making a webapp for members of my caving club to search through and view cave survey note PDFs.  It works fine, and I got the AppCache working for the web version of it.

However, since the PDFs are quite large and slow to download, and many members have the PDFs on their local machines from the same SVN the website gets them from, it would be ideal for them to be able to use a page with links to a local SVN folder of their choosing.

The design goals:

1. The site displays links to PDF files on the local filesystem
2. Whenever I add features to the site, users get them automatically the next time they open the page and they're connected to the internet
3. But after the first time they open the page, the site works offline.

Sadly web browsers don't appear to support this useful combination of design goals at once.

I can satisfy #1 by having users download a copy of the site, add their local SVN path in a JS, and open their local copy in the browser, so that `file:///` links work.

I can satisfy #2 by having absolute links to JS bundles on the server.

I can satisfy #3 by using the AppCache.

I thought I could get clever by having the copy of the page on the local file system have `<html manifest="https://myserver.com/myapp.appcache">`, but unfortunately Chrome doesn't seem to allow a local file to use an app cache manifest hosted on a server, for seemingly no good reason to me.

Does anyone know of another way I could satisfy all 3 goals?

Perhaps there's some simple program/config I could give my friends that would intercept web requests to https://myserver.com/some/folder and instead serve them out of a folder on their local file system?

Answer (score 0):

Andy,

I know this post is a bit old but came across it looking for something else related to AppCache.  My understanding it that the html page and the manifest must reside in the same domain for it to work.  So I think you need to modify your design:

1. Create a JavaScript function that acts as a setting for the user to enter the path to their local copy of the PDF's.  Store this information in localstorage.
2. Create a html template page for the document links.
3. Create a JavaScript function that populates the html template page with any documents and links the user enters.

This way, the users visit your application online and it uses appcache to store itself and the JS files for offline use.  To access the PDF's, the user clicks a settings button that launches a page to collect path information and saves the information in localstorage.  The users can then access the template page which will populate with the documents they entered.

Here is a good intro to localstorage: [http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/]

Comment: Ah, so I basically did implement something like that later on.  The only problem is that browsers don't normally permit you to open `file:///` links unless you access the page via `file:///` as well.  However, there's a Chrome plugin that allows this, so I got it working for chrome only.